# Return the aggregate functions in pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to return the aggregate functions in pl sql?

```
create or replace procedure get_empsalary(emp_dept varchar(20))
  as
    total_salary number(10,2);
    begin
    select sum(empsalary) 
      into total_salary 
      from employe 
     where empdept=emp_dept;
    dbms_output.put_line('department' || emp_dept || 
                         'salary is ' || total_salary);
 end;
```

Comment: Do you have to use a procedure?  A procedure doesn't return anything.  A function returns something.  This looks like it should be a function.  A procedure can have an OUT parameter.  But procedures should change database state-- a function is more appropriate if you are simply reading database state.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Does the above code compile but not properly return the expected data. Or doesn't it compile. Or what execatly is it you need help with?